# Force the TCP/IP protocol in connection string

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, connection-string

I have a database driven website written in asp.net. I'd like to modify the connection string to force protocol TCP. Please advise.

```xml
<add name="TESTConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Data Source=SERVER201;Initial Catalog=DB201;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=201User;Password=123!@#"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use `server=tcp:hostname` in your connection string to achieve this.

For more details, see [How to use the server name parameter in a connection string to specify the client network library](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313295)