# Disable named pipes

Tags: sql-server, tcp, named-pipes

i have this problem - client stations (which do not have SQL Server) first attempt to connect to the SQL Server via named pipes. It is possible to force these stations to connect first over the TCP / IP protocol? I have logs from the application that say that the network path has not been found (because it is trying to connect just named pipes). My question is: can a SQL server somehow force client stations to connect only through TCP / IP? SQL Server 2012 is installed on the server

[registers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2UOB.jpg)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force the TCP/IP protocol in connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430381/force-the-tcp-ip-protocol-in-connection-string)

Comment: How would the clients know what policies a server wants to enforce *before* connecting to the server?

Comment: I understand, different solution than server = tcp: hostname not?

Comment: when I tried tcp: hostname a few months ago, it did not work (I did not get it at all)...

Comment: >>>when I tried tcp: hostname a few months ago, it did not work<<< That's what I'm talking about. Even if the error you see is reported by named pipes, ALL the protocols were tried. But since you passes incorrect server name or your **SQL SERVER BROWSER** is not running you cannot connect at all

Comment: The problem is that the program communicates with the server, then drops and then communicates for 5 seconds, and I do not know if it is caused by the network (**or exactly what this is caused**)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the documentation [Client Protocols Properties (Order Tab)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187884(v=sql.105).aspx)

> Client Protocols Properties (Order Tab)
>
> Use the Orderpage on the Client Protocols Properties dialog box to
>   view and enable the client protocols.
>
> Click a protocol, and then click Enable or Disable to move the
>   selected protocol to the Disabled Protocols or Enabled Protocols list.
>
> Protocols are tried in the order listed, attempting to connect using
>   the top protocol first, and then the second listed protocol, etc. Move
>   protocols up or down the Enabled Protocols list, by clicking the up
>   arrow and down arrow buttons. When connecting to Microsoft SQL Server
>   from a client on that computer, the Shared Memory protocol will always
>   be tried first, if enabled.
>
> Note These settings are not used by Microsoft .NET SqlClient. The
>   protocol order for .NET SqlClient is first TCP, and then named pipes,
>   which cannot be changed.

protocols are tried in the order listed, and those in my picture is the default order, I mean, if noone changed the configuration, named pipes is the last:

[image]

I think your problem is not named pipes, but the wrong instance name / **SQL Server Browser that is not running**. When all the protocols were tried without success, the last one reports the error, so if your error says

> "server was not found" (named pipes)

this means that all the protocols were tried but named pipes was the last.

Comment: My answer below