# Frustrating problem connecting to SQL Server Express from C# code

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string, entity-framework-migrations

I have a program at work that connects to a SQL Server database default instance. I connect to the database using Entity Framework and the software is now used as production software - it's supported my business very well. It's a paid version of SQL Server running on Windows Server 2012.

I've checked out the same code from git at home and am hoping to work on the same software at home. I've installed SQL Server Express on my PC (and actually, for test purposes on a second PC on the network). I am using a connection string directly copied from SQL Server Object Explorer:

```
@"Data Source=TSORT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CN2;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
```

On my production software, the connection string is built from a settings file, but I've resorted to hard-coding for testing purposes.

My setup routine successfully creates the database at home on my SQL Server Express named instance. I can see the database and tables, including the `__MigrationHistory` table, which contains the correct revision.

However, when running this code:

```
CN2.Data.Model.CN2Context context = new Data.Model.CN2Context(builder.ConnectionString);

context.Database.Delete();
context.Database.Create();
var dbMigrator = new System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator(new AJSoft.CN2.Model.Migrations.Configuration());
dbMigrator.Update();
context.SaveChanges();
```

And when I subsequently try to connect to the database using the same connection string, I get the well-known, generic error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I have checked Named Pipes and TCP connections are enabled locally and on the network. When I attempted this with the database on my *remote* machine, I even resorted to turning my firewall *off* for a moment but no improvement. There is obviously some sort of connection because my empty database structures are correctly created in the first place.

The main difference at work (SQL Server) and home (SQL Server Express) is that at work I am using a default instance and home am using a named instance (`COMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS`). All client PC's are Windows 10 and kept fully updated.

This is obviously incredibly frustrating as it means I can't do any work with the software on my home PC. Any hints much appreciated.

Edit: For reference, the connection string I'm using on my debug build at work (no issues):

For reference, the connection string I'm using for my *debug* build in my domain environment at work:

```
"Data Source=ROHAN;Initial Catalog=\"CN2 Test\";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=10;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
```

Where ROHAN is obviously my server name and a default instance is used as you can see.

EDIT: It appears I have a more fundamental problem somewhere in my code. I get *exactly* the same problem having specified LocalDb - the database is created but once it has been created, I can't connect to it again. I'll continue investigating. Until then, I'm using TeamViewer to develop from home.

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem is?

Comment: The third code snippet contains the exact error text. I am unable to connect to the database after initial creation.

Comment: Are you able to connect to SQL express from SQL management studio?

Comment: So your machine is able to connect to the database to create it, but when running the program it is unable to connect? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes - I can connect from SQL management studio. Both when I try this locally and remotely. I can even "refresh" the list of databases and "watch" the empty database get created from SSMS. I've also checked the Windows user has full admin rights on the database. Same errors when I use internal authentication too.

Comment: @CiaranGallagher yes that's right. Despite copying and pasting the exact connection string. I love programming, love databases but am finding this particular issue incredibly frustrating...

Comment: Is this a web application, e.g. ASP.NET? Which version of entity framework are you using? Is it .NET Core or .NET Framework? If you can, add these additional details to your question so we can understand the situation more. Does the solution have multiple projects?

Comment: C# WPF Windows Desktop, .NET Framework 4.80. EF 6.4.0. All identical on home and work computers. The solution has 4 projects: The executable, a DLL containing my Viewmodels, a DLL containing my Model (which obviously does the actual DB communication) and a library I use to manage other things (not to do with database access. It's a pretty big project but no other libraries from sources other than Nuget.

Comment: Have you tried with ".\SQLEXPRESS" ?

Comment: No but I just did now - no change to the error.

Comment: Possible a local firewall getting in the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to try:
 1. Specify the protocol and port for the server as in: 
Data Source=tcp:TSORT,1433;
 2. Specify the IP address instead of the server name as in:
Data Source=tcp:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,1433;

Connecting directly to the port alleviates the need to have the SQL Browser service running on your DB server.

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion, and I've never seen a connection string specifying that so added to my useful SQL Server knowledge even if it doesn't work this time! I have doubts (see my edit about even (localdb) failing) but I'll give it a go this evening.

Comment: AJ, thanks.  I use this same construct, and it also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430381/force-the-tcp-ip-protocol-in-connection-string) by @RedFilter

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you've checked that TCP/IP is enabled locally and on the network... so you're 100% sure that the IP address you're trying to reach it on (a non-127.0.0.1 address) is enabled?  What port is TCP/IP bound to for your SQL Express instance?  If it's not bound to the standard port (1433), or dynamic ports are enabled, then you'll need to make sure the SQL Browser service is running on the server machine, so the client knows which port to connect to to reach that named instance... so please check that that service is running.

[Configure SQL Server to Listen on a Specific TCP Port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-ver15)

[About the SQL Server Browser Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/configuration-manager/sql-server-browser-service?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks - I'd already specified the standard port (1433) on all tcp listeners. No joy. I've edited the question with an update...

Answer (score 0):

Ok - this feels more like a confession than an answer but I hope the community won't judge me too harshly.

I've accepted BreukAJ's as the definitive answer because for any other reason, it would have been correct.

At a very early testing stage with the project, I had created a constructor on my CN2Context class marked with #ifdef DEBUG. This parameterless constructor then called a further constructor with a hard-coded connection string. This allowed me to connect to the database from the WPF designer which was useful at the earliest project stages. This was 7 years ago and only became apparent once I moved on to a different development machine with a new SQL server.

I apologise to anyone who has put time and effort in to the problem, which is now solved...