# C# and SQL Server - Error 40, could not open a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, google-cloud-sql

I have SQL server express running through Google Cloud and I connect to it via the cloud proxy. I am writing a login program through windows forms. I am able to connect to and use the sql server through Microsoft SQL Server management studio. But when I try to to open the connection with Visual Studio I get the following error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Why would it be that I can easily open it in SSMS but not through Visual Studio?

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Is SSMS using TCP/IP to connect? If Google Cloud is anything like Azure then they probably disable the Named Pipes protocol by default, ref: [Default SQL Server Network Protocol Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/default-sql-server-network-protocol-configuration)

Comment: I just had a look and a quick google search and I can't seem to find anything relating to that protocol on Google cloud.

Comment: The Named Pipes protocol is typically used in these cases: A. Your Client setup forces it to, _or_  B. It fails to connect on the usual protocol (TCP/IP) and falls back to named pipes. TCP IP is typically the protocol you should use. Step 1 is to force TCP/IP and see what error you get: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430381/force-the-tcp-ip-protocol-in-connection-string

Comment: I can't find it stated explicitly anywhere in the doco, but it does mention port 1433 so yes I think we can assume it is configured for TCP/IP and not named pipes.

Comment: Hi, Through the cloud proxy it forces me to connect through port 1433, so that makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not very clear from where are you connecting.

I have reproduced the issue without proxy and I only have to allow the IP in the GCP console in order let pass remote connections to Cloud SQL.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/configure-ip

Comment: Hi, thanks for that just using the external IP instead of using the proxy worked