# How does SqlClient choose protocol when connecting to a remote SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` (version 3.1.30) in a .NET Framework 4.8 WPF application to access a remote SQL Server 2016 Express.

On a specific instance I get this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: HTTP Provider, error: 0 - )

The connection string is specified with IP address (not a named instance) and Trust server certificates = True

I can successfully connect if I manually specify the `tcp:` protocol before IP address

Why does `SqlClient` try to select HTTP Provider in this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force the TCP/IP protocol in connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430381/force-the-tcp-ip-protocol-in-connection-string)

Comment: According to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/clients-change-protocols-when-connect-instance): _the protocol order is stored in the ProtocolOrder registry entry under the following registry subkey: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\SNI<version>`_. The following may also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199793/10024425

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access my SQL Server via C# form application from client device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71198996/cant-access-my-sql-server-via-c-sharp-form-application-from-client-device)